# Rename log file in Python while file keeps writing any other logs

Tags: python, json, logging, rename

I am using the Python logger mechanism for keeping a record of my logs. I have two types of logs,
one is the Rotating log (log1, log2, log3...) and a non-rotating log called json.log (which has json logs in it as the name suggests).
The log files are created when the server is started and close when the app is closed.

What I am trying to do in general is: When I press the import button on my page, to have all json logs saved on the sqlite db.

The problem I am facing is:
When I try to rename the json.log file like this:

```
source_file = "./logs/json.log"
snapshot_file = "./logs/json.snapshot.log"

try:
   os.rename(source_file, snapshot_file)
```

I get the `windowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

and this is because the file is being used by the logger continuously. Therefore, I need to "close" the file somehow so I can do my I/O operation successfully. 
The thing is that this is not desirable because logs might be lost until the file is closed, then renamed and then "re-created".

I was wondering if anyone came across such scenario again and if any practical solution was found.

I have tried something which works but does not seem convenient and not sure if it is safe so that any logs are not lost.

My code is this:

```
source_file = "./logs/json.log"
snapshot_file = "./logs/json.snapshot.log"

try:
    logger = get_logger()


    # some hackish way to remove the handler for json.log 

    if len(logger.handlers) > 2:
        logger.removeHandler(logger.handlers[2])
    if not os.path.exists(snapshot_file):
        os.rename(source_file, snapshot_file)

    try:
        if type(logger.handlers[2]) == RequestLoggerHandler:
            del logger.handlers[2]
    except IndexError:
        pass


    # re-adding the logs file handler so it continues writing the logs

    json_file_name = configuration["brew.log_file_dir"] + os.sep + "json.log"
    json_log_level = logging.DEBUG
    json_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(json_file_name)
    json_file_handler.setLevel(json_log_level)
    json_file_handler.addFilter(JSONLoggerFiltering())
    json_file_handler.setFormatter(JSONFormatter())
    logger.addHandler(json_file_handler)

... code continues to write the logs to the db and then delete the json.snapshot.file 
until the next time the import button is pressed; then the snapshot is created again 
only for writing the logs to the db.
```

Also for reference my log file has this format:

```
{'status': 200, 'actual_user': 1, 'resource_name': '/core/logs/process', 'log_level': 'INFO', 'request_body': None, ... }
```

Thanks in advance :)